# add element after specifiec element in linked list and delete first element

Tags: c++

I tried hard to solve this problem but only managed to partially solve it.

My problem in this method is that I need to add an element after another element:

**Example: `add 5 1`**

5 is an element in the linked list but I want to add 1 after 5.

**Example: let linked list contains these elements : 2 3 7**

I call method to add 1 after 3, `add 3 1`, so the result assume to be `2 3 1 7`, but with my method the result is  `2 1 3 7`, which is my problem.

Second problem is that I can't deal with the first element:

**Example: `add 2 1`**

It acts as if the first element does not exist:

```
void addNodeAtPos(link *head, int pos,int addelement)
{
  link prev=NULL;

  link curr =*head;

  link newNode = (link)malloc(sizeof(node));

  newNode->data = addelement;


    while(curr->next != NULL )
    {

              prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;


         if(curr->data == pos)
    {

        newNode->next = curr;
        prev->next = newNode;

        break;
    }
    }

    }
```

My problem here is that I can't remove the first element:

```
void deletenode(link *head,int s){

    bool found = false;

    node *curr = *head, *prev=NULL;

    while(curr != NULL){

        // match found, delete
        if(curr->data == s){

            found = true;
            // found at top

            if(prev == NULL){

                link temp = *head;

                curr->next= prev;
                delete(temp);
                // found in list - not top
            }else{
                prev->next = curr->next;
                delete(curr);
            } }
        // not found, advance pointers
       if(!found){
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next; }
        // found, exit loop
        else curr = NULL; }




     }
```

Comment: I suggest you run your program in a debugger, and step through the insertion function line by line. Your insertion problems should become very obvious then. Including another problem, namely that you can't insert a new first node.

Comment: The problem is at this point
`newNode->next = curr;
prev->next = newNode;`

It should be corrected.

Comment: Also, if you have two problems with two different functions, you should ask two questions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If this is C++, the cast will be needed.

Comment: @Yann4 That's true, which makes me wonder why the OP uses `malloc` to allocate nodes, and `delete` to free them?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Good point. OP, you need to use `free` to clean up memory allocated by `malloc`. You use `delete` to clean up memory allocated by `new`. So either chance your `malloc`s to `new`s, or your `delete`s to `free`s. I think I'd personally change `malloc` to `new`.

Comment: I have solved second problem , after modifying the code to be 

while(curr->next != NULL )
    {

        if(curr->data == pos)
                             {
  tempNode = curr->next;
  curr->next = newNode;
  newNode->next = tempNode;
  break;
                             }

         prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

Comment: now ,I need help to can delete first element in linked list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution to the first problem

```
if(curr->data == pos)
{
  // tempNode = curr->next;
  // improvement as suggested by @Rerito
  newNode->next = curr->next;
  curr->next = newNode;
  break;
}
```

Comment: I solved it also with other way but third problem about delete first element still remaining need help in it

Comment: You don't solve the second problem. `curr` is a local variable, it won't fix anything to update it.

Comment: Moreover, you could make the assignments : `newNode->next = curr->next; curr->next = newNode;` in that specific order to avoid the use of any temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using non-circular doubly linked lists. Thus, both ends of the list are marked with `NULL`. Now, it seems to me that you use C++ in a very C-esque fashion ... (`NULL` would'nt be used in C++, there is the `nullptr` keyword).

I will deal with your issues assuming you are using C instead of C++.

```
// Note that I pass a link **ptr, NOT a link *ptr ...
void addNodeAtPos(link **head, int pos, int addelement) {
    // I am assuming head will be a valid pointer, if not, please add the appropriate checks.
    link *newNode = NULL, *cur = *head;
    if (NULL == (newNode = malloc(sizeof(link)))
        return;
    newNode->data = addelement;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (cur->data == pos || NULL == cur->next) {
            newNode->next = cur->next;
            newNode->prev = cur; // remove this line if there is no prev pointer.
            cur->next = newNode;
            if (NULL != newNode->next) { // remove this if clause if there is no prev pointer
                newNode->next->prev = newNode;
            }
            break;
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

You did not specify what you should do if the "position" is not found, I assumed that you just add the element at the end of the list in that case.

Now, considering your issue removing the first element :

```
void deleteNode(link **head, int el)
{
    // I assume you wont pass a `NULL` ptr as @head
    link *cur = *head, *prev = NULL;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (cur->data == el) {
            next = cur->next;
            prev = cur->prev;
            free(cur);
            if (NULL != next)
               next->prev = prev;
            if (NULL != prev)
                prev->next = next;
            else
                *head = next;
            break;
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

Why do you need to pass a `link **head` instead of a `link *head` ? Because when you are removing the head of the list, you must make sure it won't be accessed anymore and thus you need to update the head pointer you use elsewhere. This is what is made in the `*head = next;` statement in the above function.

If you are using singly linked list (only a pointer to the next element, not the previous), the solution becomes the following :

```
void deleteNode(link **head, int el)
{
    // I assume you wont pass a `NULL` ptr as @head
    link *cur = *head, *prev = NULL, *next = NULL;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (cur->data == el) {
            if (NULL != prev)
                prev->next = cur->next;
            else
                *head = cur->next;
            free(cur);
            break;
        }
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```